# how to use objects.filter() for filtering a dictionary to a POST method in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='category', null= True, blank= False)
    image = models.ImageField(null= False, blank = False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']


class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['id','category','image','description']
```

view.py

```
from django.http import response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Category, Photo
from .serializers import PhotoSerializer


class DisplayAllViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

class DisplayCategoryViseViewSet(APIView):
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = self.request.data
        print(data)
        category = data['category']
        print(category)
        print(category['name'])
        name=category['name']
        queryset = Photo.objects.filter(category=name)
        serializer = PhotoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(Serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from re import I
from django.db import router
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import DisplayAllViewSet, DisplayCategoryViseViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('allImages',DisplayAllViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('category',DisplayCategoryViseViewSet.as_view()),
]
```

In Postman : GET request
http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/allImages

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "name": "Sirsi"
        },
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sunset.jpg",
        "description": "Sunset view point"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": {
            "name": "Chickmangluru"
        },
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tiger.jpg",
        "description": "cheeta"
    }
]
```

In Postman: POST request
http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/category
Body:

```
{
    "category":{
        "name":"Sirsi"
    }
}
```

ValueError : Field 'id' is expected a number but got 'Sirsi'

I am not able to map request data with filter(category=name)
I know category is a Dict, But do we use Dict to map with name(Sirsi) in filter? to retrive the api using category wise.

Desired Outcome:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "name": "Sirsi"
        },
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sunset.jpg",
        "description": "Sunset view point"
    },
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `post` method of `DisplayCategoryViseViewSet` you need to make two changes as shown below. changes are added as comments in the code

```
class DisplayCategoryViseViewSet(APIView):
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = self.request.data
        print(data)
        category = data['category']
        print(category)
        print(category['name'])
        name=category['name']
        queryset = Photo.objects.filter(category__name=name) #Since you are passing name, if you are passing id of the category, you can give category=name
        print(queryset[0])
        serializer = PhotoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)  #Typo , Serializer should be serializer
```